# Associativity Question , Computer organization

Tags: computer-architecture

an access sequence of cache block address of length N and contaons n unique addresses. The no. of unique block address between 2 consecutive accesses to the same block address is bound above by k. What is miss ratio if access sequence is passed through a cache of associativity A >= k exercising LRU replacement policy? Ans is n/N but how?

Problem : I m not understanding what is meant by an access sequence of cache block address of length N ? Describe it and give answer of whole question .

Answer (score 0):

An *access sequence* is a sequence of accesses.  The length of the sequence is the number of accesses it contains.  In this case, each access is an access to an address.  So that should help you decode what is meant by "an access sequence of cache block address".

As far as solving the problem, it's your exercise so I'll let you have the joy of solving it.  I suggest that you try working through some examples with small values of $N$ and $k$.  For instance, try $k=1$ and $N=10$ and try to work out some examples of access sequences, and for each compute what the miss ratio is (by hand).  See if you spot a pattern.

A tip on how to parse the language: They are talking about an access sequence of length N, where each element in the sequence is a cache block address.  Don't read it as "cache block addresses of length N": I don't know what that would mean either, and it's probably not what they intended.

Comment: i know these things well . If there is k associativity let k =4 . and there is need to map 16 blocks . then we make 16/4 sets . and each set map 4 blocks by using n mod 4 formula .

Comment: i m not getting here what does it mean -> cache block address of length N .  Is that means a block consists of N words ? Plz first simply the question . If u do that ...then i m sure i will give answer to u accurately.

Comment: @sittian, see revised answer: the last paragraph answers your follow-up question.